# IndexError: Index out of range in self while implementing transformer model for translation

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

I am trying to implement a transformer model for the translation task, from some youtube tutorials. But I am getting the index out-of-range error. It seems The problem is with the input dimensions, but I can't figure it out.
[Here is the code (google colab link)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JXlkB6x0tsBSd2R1LV_Njo8YaiuxzaeF?usp=sharing)

[You can find the datasets here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12qtb8w1gSUG4_CykUT5KpMVHp-E_y7BT?usp=sharing)

I tried to change the dimensions but It didn't help or I couldn't do it correctly. I hope someone can help solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please check the dim for src and tar language which should be in same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your code and found out that in the error trace of yours **(error in `forward` call of `SentenceEmbedding`, `encoder` stage)**

> ```
> 69 def forward(self, x, start_token, end_token): # sentence  
> 70      x = self.batch_tokenize(x, start_token, end_token)   
> 71 ---> x = self.embedding(x)  
> 72      pos = self.position_encoder().to(get_device())  
> 73      x = self.dropout(x + pos)
> ```

If you add `print(torch.max(x))` before the line `x = self.embedding(x)`

Then you can see that the error is because `x` contains `id` that is **>=68**.  If the value is greater than 68, then Pytorch will raise the error mentioned in the stack trace.

It means that while you are converting `tokens` to `ids`, you are assigning a value greater than **68**.

#### **To prove my point:**

when you are creating `english_to_index`, since there are three `""` in your `english_vocabulary` (`START_TOKEN`, `PADDING_TOKEN`, `END_TOKEN` are all `""`) you end up generating `{ "": 69 }`. Since this value is greater than the `len(english_to_index) # length = 68`.
Hence, you are getting **`IndexError: index out of range in self`**

#### Solution

As a solution, you can give unique tags to these tokens (which is generally prescribed) as:

```
START_TOKEN = "START"
PADDING_TOKEN = "PAD"
END_TOKEN = "END"
```

This will make sure that the generated dictionaries will have the correct sizes.
Please find the working Google Colaboratory file [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qkmP4gA1SurfCrfZq92RQGKJZMrafTq1?usp=sharing) with the solution section.

I added `'\\'` to the `english_vocabulary` since after a few iterations we get a `KeyError: '\\'`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked and thanks for the explanation. Now I understand the error. Can't thank you enough man. Have a nice day :)